# Google App Engine won't launch on NetBeans - Stuck on Deploy

Tags: java, google-app-engine, netbeans

I've tried for longer than I'd like to admit and I've tried using NetBeans 6.9 to 7.1.2 and I've tried using multiple JDKs and such.

I'm following the directions here: http://rocky.developerblogs.com/tutorials/getting-started-google-app-engine-netbeans/ and I'm trying to simply run the Guestbook sample project in NetBeans.

I've gone into System Properties and edited/created the following variables:

```
ANT_HOME: C:\Program Files\NetBeans 6.9\java\ant
CLASSPATH: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_31
JAVA_HOME: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_31
PATH: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_31\bin
```

Despite changing the variables, NetBeans would run the project and kept saying it couldn't find `tools.jar`.  I ended up just copying `tools.jar` into the folder it was looking in (kept looking in the JRE folder... I couldn't change it no matter what).

The program runs "fine", but it gets stuck when it starts up Google App Engine and tries to deploy the project, but nothing happens... it just sits there and does nothing... I've noticed that in the Services tab, the icon for Google App Engine has a little time glass and never gets the green play icon...

Any ideas? Is it an Ant issue?  I'm sorry if this is basic - I've been trying to do this for several days now...

Comment: I use GAE/J and NetBeans 7.1. One thing you haven't mentioned is your `war` folder. Do you set NetBeans up to build such a folder to meet the GAE/J requirements, and then set your GAE/J dev server to look there?

Comment: Netbeans says in the console that it's building the war file and deploying it to GAE... I was under the impression that Netbeans does this automatically when it builds the project.  How can I set this up properly?

Comment: The trouble may be that the Google App Engine NetBeans plug-in mentioned in the blog is nearly 3 years old. I stopped using this plug-in and use NetBeans without any. You might care to follow the "Getting Started: Java" chapter in the official GAE documentation. This will tell you how to configure Apache Ant (I use this) if you want to use this to manage your build process.

Comment: The blog post itself is over 2 years old. Perhaps the basics of GAE have not changed since then, but I recommend that you try the GAE introduction since that should be more up-to-date.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I had read over some of that, but I'll read it over again and go from there.  Appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is code to add within appengine-web.xml :

```
<!-- TODO review code for thread-safety. -->
<threadsafe>false</threadsafe>
```

Answer (score 2):

**nice news for Netbeans users of GAE-Java projects !**

it's possible obtain a good plug-in for Netbeans 7.3 and GAE Java SDK v.1.8  from this repository:
 https://github.com/Valery-Sh/NbAppEngine

with this plug-in, GAE projects like guestbook sample or new personal projects are running very fine..

Method:
1. delete completely App Engine server of your Netbeans (I had to reinstall Netbeans to remove the service completely, but there must be a way to do it)
2. download plug-in from : https://code.google.com/p/nb-gaelyk-plugin/downloads/detail?name=nbappengine-7.3-gae1.8.x.zip to any folder..
3. install plug-in : Tools / Plugins / Downloaded
4. verify update of plugins..
5. create a new server appengine with version 1.8.x of SDK for Java
6. create a new JavaWeb project for running on appengine server and/or testing guestbook sample..


..and this is all !
best regards
@Mlaynes

Answer (score 0):

consider the following:

1. with Netbeans version 7.2 :
   GuestBook sample throws "Missing value for property jvmargs" message.. (kenai problem)
   and can not create new project appengine (netbeans problem)
2. with Netbeans version 7.1.2 and previous, only need to add the following statement in appengine-web.xml :

   false

   and all works fine !
   ( both "guestbook" sample so as in new projects )